# Is it somehow possible to predict / foresee when SQL Server will trigger auto-growth?

Tags: sql-server

I found numerous questions / answers about SQL-Server auto-growth - almost all indicating that one should try to avoid auto-growth if possible.

However auto-growth is available with MS SQL Server and sometimes required.

Is there any way how one could predict when SQL Server will trigger it's next auto-growth event or is this calculation completely internal to SQL Server?

(E.g. is there some kind of "fill-level" in settings which SQL Server compares to the current database usage and then triggers auto-growth when this fill-level will be reached?)

BR
Mark

Comment: @JonSeigel this is more precise now. My question is about auto-growth. (I wasn't even aware there's auto-shrink too. Is it?)

Comment: There is.  It should be avoided.  http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/08/stop-shrinking-your-database-files-seriously-now/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way is to go based off of previous events, and one way to do that is to use a trace to start capturing history.

- https://sqlblog.org/2007/01/11/reviewing-autogrow-events-from-the-default-trace

Also some ideas here:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/33329/how-can-i-get-alerted-when-auto-growth-occurs-on-a-sql-server-database
- http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/autogrowth/93229/

As you can see, there are many ways to approach this.  Let me know what you think.

Comment: Thank you for these useful links! What I learned from those is that we can either try to predict future auto-growth events from evaluating past auto-growth log data or we can set event notifications for currently happening auto-growth actions. As long as nobody comes up with something better log data evaluation will be my best bet so far. But how to predict the very first auto-growth operation (when there's no log data available)?

Comment: That will be tricky.  You could compare it to other systems based off their load (if that's possible), but really that's a tough one that maybe someone else could give some advice.

Answer (score 1):

Know your app.

If your database has 14 GB of free space in the data files and your app is generating 2 GB of activity a day then there will be an auto-growth event in 7 days. If your database is set to "Autogrow by 4 GB" then there will be an auto-growth event every 2 days after that.

[Data Collection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677179.aspx) is an easy-to-set-up monitoring system that allows you too look at the history f database growth for a number of servers.